# Why does onclientclick override by custom validator?

Tags: .net, events, onclick, buttonclick, onclientclick

I have a typical .net form scenario with a custom validator and a button.

The custom validator has the property ClientValidationFunction set.

When I use the onclick event on the button everything fires ok, however when I use the built in OnClientClick event the custom validator doesn't fire.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attaching anything to the button's client click event, be sure it isn't returning false, otherwise your form will not submit and validation will not be called.

For information on how to trigger client-side validation, see this page:

http://fczaja.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/aspnet-how-to-trigger-client-side.html